# Stack components centered above each other in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to place two (or more) components above each others, centered vertically and horizontally in a view that wraps this content (i.e., the height of this outer view should be the max height of the components inside; idem for the width).

At first, absolute positioning looked like a good idea to have all the components centered above each other. However then I don't know how to get the outer view to wrap the content.

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: 70, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: 50, height: 70, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
</View>
```

With this examples, we cannot see any of the black background of the outer View (whose size is probable 0x0), whereas I'm expecting a 70x70 black square behind the three colored rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

The outermost View will not automatically adjust to its children if their position is absolute.

You would have to make the outermost View's position absolute and calculate its size and position based on its children and the screen's width and height.

Another option is to create a background View as a child with a position of relative like this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}> 
  <View style={{position: 'relative', width: 70, height: 70, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
  <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
  <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: 70, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
  <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: 50, height: 70, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks.
In this example I have used hard-coded widths and heights, but in the general case, is there a non-dynamic solution when one doesn't know in advance these dimensions? Maybe without absolute positions…
(In native Android it's quite easy to do with layout_height/width for the outer view and layout_centerInParent for the inside components.)

Comment: Like I said in the answer, not if you're using a position of absolute on the children.

Comment: Ok. Using absolute positions was simply a guess of mine. Is there a solution with relative positions?

Comment: Yes. The outermost view will automatically adjust to the sum of the dimensions of all the children with relative position. There should be in your case exactly one View with relative position that acts as a kind of container with the maximum width and height.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If all views have relative positions, I don't know how to get the components to be on top of each other.
Maybe you were saying that I should add a background View with relative position and leave the other components with absolute positions (as in your code), but then, what should I do if I don't know in advance the dimensions of the components?

Comment: If you want to use absolute positioning, you'll have to. Otherwise, you'll need to use something like flex-box. It's a problem we all have unfortunately. :( Most of the time I don't use pixels at all, just percents.